# How to enable remote desktop from remote?

Tags: remote-desktop

Most of the times after installing ubuntu, we forget to enable Remote Desktop. How ever we have installed ssh in all the ubuntu systems. Is it possible to enable Remote Desktop remotely? It will be helpful for us if it is possible.. I hope someone will write a possible solution, thanks in advance..

Comment: If you want the vino-server to be running at system startup - do you run vino-server directy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNOME VNC-server vino is started from the command line with:

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

This can also be done remotely in a SSH session.

Settings for vino need to be made on the remote, e.g. by editing `/desktop/gnome/remote_access` with **gconftool-2**, from the GUI, or by using **gconf-editor**, or in a GUI with

```
vino-preferences
```

This can also be done from an X-forwarding enabled SSH session.

Comment: `vino-server` shouldn't be called directly from the user. It is activated/deactivated automatically from `vino-preferences`. Moreover, `vino-preferences` do not require root privileges.

Comment: @enzotib: ty for this. I erroneously thought this was for a root access (which it is not of course) - corrected :)