# Problem when creating new partitions?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I've created a new disk partition by `sudo fdisk /dev/xvda1` and the following commands:

1. <kbd>n</kbd>
2. <kbd>p</kbd>
3. <kbd>1</kbd>
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. <kbd>w</kbd>

After, when I want to change the partition system file into xfs by `sudo mkfs.xfs -i size=1024 /dev/xvda1p1` I got:

```
/dev/xvda1p1: Not such file or directory
```

P.S. : `xvda1p1` is the name of the new created partition when I type `sudo fdisk -l`

I'm following these instructions in order to achieve a tutorial of creating a Swift Cluster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/xvda1` *is* a partition.  You don't create partitions inside partitions.  You wanted `fdisk /dev/xvda`.

Comment: And the resulting name of the first primary partition for `/dev/xvda` is `/dev/xvda1`.  The partition number gets appended to the base disk name, NOT p#.

Comment: ah ok, so what does it mean when i got after typing "fdisk -l"                                                                Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
86 heads, 1 sectors/track, 195083 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5cd8852f

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1p1            2048    16777215     8387584   83  Linux

Comment: @psusi when i type "fdisk /dev/xvda" i got "fdisk: unable to open /dev/xvda: No such file or directory" !!

Comment: @user1959686, add the contents of /proc/partitions to your question.

Comment: @psusi                                                        major minor  #blocks  name     202        1    8388608 xvda1

Comment: @user1959686, put the whole file in your question, not one line in a comment.

Comment: @psusi yes i put the whole file, i found juste one line in the file, its a new Ubuntu instance running on Amazon cloud.

Comment: @user1959686, then your vm is misconfigured.  Normally it isn't possible to have a partition with no underlying disk, but I guess it is with xen if you configure it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you could install gparted to make it easier. You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: i'm on a remote machine, i can't acess to Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: @user1959686 Assuming you use ssh to get to it, if you want you can get a remote desktop to the machine. TinyVNC comes preinstalled but you have to change permissions first. I found something this on ask.ubuntu [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55184/change-remote-desktop-permissions-from-the-command-line-remotely)

Comment: yes i will see with that, even if later i will continue with command line, thank's