# How to setup Remote desktop sharing?

Tags: 11.04, remote-desktop, openssh

I am using `Ubuntu 11.04` and I want to know how can I access another one of my friends system using `Ubuntu 11.04` over `remote desktop`.I have installed `openssh-server`,Now what will be the next step to access his system?Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your friend needs to install ssh server, then you can ssh in:

```
ssh friends_username@server
```

For example:

```
ssh friend@192.168.1.100
```

However, arguarbly the easiest solution would be [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx?cdsplit=C).

Answer (score 0):

On the remote machine we need to start the  **vino-server** (default GNOME VNC server) or edit the **vino-preferences** for remote desktop viewing. This can also be done from an [ssh session](https://askubuntu.com/q/51925/3940) (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48348/3940)).

To view the remote desktop we simply start our VNC viewer using the `-via` option

```
vncviewer -via user@remote localhost:0
```

for secure ssh transmission (see also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/25192/3940) that also includes a solution for viewing the login screen).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to access a remote machine, two of the most popular are VNC(for graphical experience like remote-desktop in Windows) and there's SSH which is command-line remote access.

So if you want a command-line remote access, setup OpenSSH on the server and use ssh command on the client.
if you want a graphical remote access, setup vino on the server(if you're using Gnome or Unity) and use vinagre on the client.

Here are the respective documentation pages for [SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH), [vino](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) and [vinagre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vinagre)

Note that SSH also works for graphical applications but it's not very suitable for a full graphical remote-access experience.

Comment: I want the graphical access.So which one will be more helpful?

Comment: Go for vino on the server and vinagre on the client then.